# How do I copy a directory?

Tags: vb.net, copy, directory, move

I want to copy one directory from one location to another but while copying I am getting an error message:

"`Could not complete operation on some files and directories. See the Data property of the exception for more details.`" i don't know what is the problem

I tried:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, System.IO.Path.Combine(curDir, filename.Name))
```

and

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, System.IO.Path.Combine(curDir, filename.Name))
```

But I am still getting same message .

Any pointers on how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you concatenate a filename to the curDir variable? The second argument of CopyDirectory should be another Folder

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
Process.StartInfo.Filename = "xcopy"
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", sourcedir, destdir, xcopyflags)
Process.Start()
```

If you're not sure of the flags or usage you can open a command prompt and type

```
xcopy /?
```